# use unrar.dll in a c# project to retrieve the list of file and relative CRC code

Tags: c#

from this link
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/022a0806-bb30-4cea-b446-bc20c7dd4838/extracting-files-using-rarprocessfile-of-unrardll-doesnt-work?forum=csharpgeneral

I have copy all the code found at the following link at the second post...The program works but it extract all files while I want make a txt file in the same directory where there is the rar file with a list of the name of file and crc code;

so I have edited the line code

```
CharToOem("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\New Folder", sbDir);
```

into

```
CharToOem(ExtractDir, sbDir);
```

to make txt file in the same directory, but I must edit the following line code

```
while (RARReadHeader(lHandle, ref uHeader) == 0)
  {
    int result = RARProcessFile(lHandle, 2, sbDir.ToString(), null);
    if (0 != result)
      MessageBox.Show("Unable to open the Archieve!!!");
  }
```

to create a txt file and write name of all files (with "uHeader.FileName;") and crc (with "uHeader.FileCRC;"); how can I scroll all the files in the rar archive?

Answer (score 0):

See webpage : http://www.rarlab.com/technote.htm,  You have to find the end of each header to get next header.  Not easy since the header has strings of variable length (terminate with a '\0').  The integer sizes are fixed at 4 bytes.  So you have to write a routine that parses the header to find next header.

The format is following

```
General archive layout

    Self-extracting module (optional)
    RAR 5.0 signature
    Archive encryption header (optional)
    Main archive header
    Archive comment service header (optional)

    File header 1
    Service headers (NTFS ACL, streams, etc.) for preceding file (optional).
    ...
    File header N
    Service headers (NTFS ACL, streams, etc.) for preceding file (optional).

    Recovery record (optional).
    End of archive header.
```

Comment: I don't have understand...how can I access to each file header?

Comment: How score every time 260 bytes? Can you write the code to edit from microsoft forum topic linked in first post?

Comment: I don't have never used dll external moreover :(

Comment: I'll help as needed.  It looks like it is easier than I expected.  The service notes for 'File header and service header' shows that first byte is size of header.  Which will make it easier to enumerate through headers.

Comment: Do you want to use the 3rd party unrar.dll or write your own code to retrieve files?  With the tech notes you can write your own.  Good learning experience if you never interfaced with c++ before.

Comment: I'm interesting on both the solution :) the first to learn the use of external dll, the second to make code at a low level